# Chart JS - Add Interpolation points in order to highlight a segment

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs

**Background** - I'm trying to highlight a Segment of points (via the `segment.backgroundColor`  API) that are not necessarily a part of the graph.
if my data is

```
const data = [{ x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 3, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 1}]
```

I'd like to highlight the segment between `x == 2` and `x == 4`

To do this, I assume it'd be best to manually add `{x: 2 y: 1}` and `{x: 4, y: 1}` to the graph.

**The problem** - I don't know the `y` values `x==2` and `x==4` will need to have on the actual graph

**My Question** - Is there a way to ask `charts.js` to automatically derive the `y` values? either through config or the data points themselves, something like:

```
// NOT ACTUAL CODE
const data = [
  {x: 1, y: 1},
  {x: 3, y: 1},
  {x: 5, y: 1},
  {x: 4 y: 'auto/interpolate'},
  {x: 2, y: 'auto/interpolate'}]
// NOT ACTUAL CODE
```

or

```js
const datasets =
 [{ data, autoInterpolateMissingPoints: true }] //NOT ACTUAL CODE
```

Comment: You can take a look at the source of the croshair plugin and see how they got the values, then use the same method to calculate your missing values